# The asset "application.js" is not present in the asset pipeline in Rails 6

Tags: asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-6

I am creating a RoR-6 app and I get the following error thrown from application.html.erb file from this line:

```
javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
```

I get the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error: The asset "application.js" is not present in the asset pipeline.
```

The app was created by running `rails new myapp -d postgres`

I am using rails 6.0.0.rc1

Answer (score 14):

You'll want to use [`javascript_pack_tag`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/webpacker/Webpacker%2FHelper:javascript_pack_tag) instead of `javascript_include_tag`:

```
javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
```

This is required because [webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker) handles javascript compilation in Rails 6.

Comment: Thanks. This solved the problem. I appreciate your quick response.

Comment: Worth noting that it's incorrect to say webpacker handles asset compilation in Rails 6.0.0 - webpacker handles _javascript_ compilation only by default. Rails Asset Pipeline and Sprockets is still used for CSS, images and other asset types.

Comment: Having the same problem in production and using the javascript_pack_tag, any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

If you do *not* want to use Webpack, add the following to `config/initializers/assets.rb`:

```rb
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(application.js)
```

Answer (score 1):

Running `yarn build` solved the issue for me (which in the first place was caused by running `rails assets:clobber`)

Comment: damn, I found my own solution to help me 3 months down the line. can confirm again that this works.

Answer (score 0):

Place this line in the `application.html.erb`:

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
```

This worked on my end.